# In relation to TPM specification, what are (e.g.) Apple's T2 or Google's Titan chips?

Tags: tpm, trusted-computing

I understand that TPM is a specification and devices conforming to it are called Trusted Platform Modules and they play an important role in trusted computing (as is defined by the same people who make the TPM specifications in the first place). What are, in relation to this, for example Apple's T2 chip or Google's Titan chip? Are they pseudo-TPMs? Are they TPMs? Are they something completely different and/or unrelated to the standard of Trusted Computing?

Are they TPM alternatives? I guess what I am asking is if there is a name for these technologies

Comment: They are called TEE. See [What are the differences between HSM and SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/209116/118310)

Comment: I was under that impression. Thank you very much!